# Why $scope.data.task is undefine?

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have a select that I fill with a function in angular. But when I reload the page (f5) the $ scope.data.tasks is undefined
This is my html

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
<label>
<select class="w-full form-control col-sm-10" ng-model="data.category"  ng-options="cantTasksByCat(category) for category in categoriesEx  | orderBy:'title'" ></select>
</label>
</div>
```

this is my js

```
app.controller('TasksCtrl', ['$scope',  'api', 'toaster', function($scope, api, toaster, ) {
   $scope.data = {
  tasks: [],
  category: tempCat,
  selectedTask: null

};
$scope.data.tasks = $scope.tasks;

$scope.cantTasksByCat = function (cat) {
  let cantTasksByCategory;
  if (cat.title.en==='View all'){
    cantTasksByCategory= $scope.tasks;
    return " (" + cantTasksByCategory.length + ")";
  }  
  cantTasksByCategory = $scope.tasks.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.category.objectId== cat.objectId;
});
  return " (" + cantTasksByCategory.length + ")"; };}]);
```

I want to load
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anN4q.jpg)

The select fills up correctly, but when I reload the browser (f5), it flags me an error. $ Scope.data.tasks is undefined.Like that has not yet been able to get the request

Comment: we need a practical code sample that includes $scope.data.tasks

Comment: Reports of differences in Angular's behaviour on initial load/reload are not exactly rare. Try searching StackOverflow for solutions.

Comment: Need more detail code or online source (like JsFiddle) to check the error